# dmesg - "new high-speed USB device" repeated forever

Tags: debian, usb, kernel-modules, dmesg

I am on Debian Jessie 8.5 64bit on a VAIO laptop. If I run `dmesg` on my system, I get the following:

```
[ 1031.025538] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 62 using ehci-pci
[ 1031.293612] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 63 using ehci-pci
[ 1031.561688] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 64 using ehci-pci
[ 1031.829732] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 65 using ehci-pci
[ 1032.097848] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 66 using ehci-pci
[ 1032.365915] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 67 using ehci-pci
[ 1032.633993] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 68 using ehci-pci
```

The message above is repeated forever, with the numbers getting up to 127 and then starting again.

I do not have any usb connected besides an optical mouse, and if I detach it the message doesn't change nor stop.

What is causing this and how can I stop this from happening? I'm thinking about an hardware problem, but if that was really the case, should I not be seeing error messages instead?

The following is the output of the `lspci` command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5000 Series]
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
03:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller
03:00.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5U2xx (R5U230 / R5U231 / R5U241) [Memory Stick Host Controller]
03:00.4 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB] (rev 11)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Here is the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04b3:310c IBM Corp. Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6409 Microdia Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

UPDATE: Apparently the USB device that caused the problem was the Microdia Webcam, `0c45:6409`. The `lsusb` above is what is shown when the device is recognized, but when I get the "found USB device" loop, the webcam is not in there. I didn't notice this at first because it has been a while since I used it, and never noticed problems with it. Apparently, the system sometimes recognizes the device, sometimes it doesn't. Rebooting doesn't help at all, apprarently it is completely random. I am still not really sure as for why this happens, will see if this behaviour happens again in the future or got somehow stable.

Comment: You might want to add the output of `lsusb`

Comment: The issue seems to have solved itself overnight, which is weird because yesterday I rebooted three times and the problem didn't disappear. I still want to know what caused this behaviour. I added the lsusb output to the post.

Comment: (usb 1-1.2) - bus 1, port 1 I think. Device 2? Someone more familiar with this terminology may help.

Comment: According to the following link, [What are the sysfs structures for Linux USB?](http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#i6), usb 1-1.2 stands for the hub on bus 1, port 1 (1-1), second port of the hub (2). However, I only have one externally accessible hub, and that is hub 2-1. I don't know how can I get more info on what kind of device it is. I have a bluetooth device on the same hub, but it is collocated on 1-1.6

Answer (score 0):

I just unplug poor functional device. Here was cardreader

`lsusb` before and after unplug:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 22d9:2767  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Flood at logs is stopped

Comment: Thank you. I completely forgot that I had a card reader connected in my internal usb header.